# How to use SELECT element in HTML when we have a large set of values (like more than 100) to select from?

Tags: html, forms, select, dropdown

In the below html, I think it is not efficient to create individually all the 100+ values. So is there any alternative to it?

```
<form action="">
    <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
    <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        .
        .
        <!-- more than 100 such values-->
        .
        .
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There's no standard form element which is better for this scenario.  But there are multiple JS libraries out there that can help.  Have a look at Select2 for example.
https://select2.org/

Comment: You might want to consider an autocomplete type element so that the user can type in part of a name and get suggested matches. For example [jQueryUI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)